# xindy: confused by conflicting information

Tags: errors, xindy

Trying to create a properly sorted Russian index, I ran into the below error with `xindy`:

> ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string

[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128277) it says that this error is from an "older" version of `xindy` but its homepage lists v. 2.1 while my TexLive distribution comes with 2.5.1:

```
$ xindy -V
xindy release: 2.5.1
xindy script version: 1.18
xindy kernel version: 3.0
CLISP version 2.49.92 (2018-02-18) (built on bulldog [127.0.0.1])
    architecture: X86_64
```

What steps should I take to arrive at the properly sorted Russian index?

The full log printed by `xindy` follows:

```
$texindy -L russian -C utf8 "document.idx"
Opening logfile "/dev/null" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "/tmp/UnwOZdterz"...
Loading module "lang/russian/utf8-lang.xdy"...
Loading module "lang/russian/utf8.xdy"...
Finished loading module "lang/russian/utf8.xdy".
Finished loading module "lang/russian/utf8-lang.xdy".
Loading module "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy".
Loading module "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base/texindy.xdy"...
Loading module "numeric-sort.xdy"...
Finished loading module "numeric-sort.xdy".
Loading module "latex.xdy"...
Loading module "tex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex.xdy".
Finished loading module "latex.xdy".
Loading module "latex-loc-fmts.xdy"...
Finished loading module "latex-loc-fmts.xdy".
Loading module "makeindex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "makeindex.xdy".
Loading module "latin-lettergroups.xdy"...
Finished loading module "latin-lettergroups.xdy".
Finished loading module "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base/texindy.xdy".
Loading module "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base/page-ranges.xdy"...
Finished loading module "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base/page-ranges.xdy".
Loading module "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base/word-order.xdy"...
Finished loading module "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base/word-order.xdy".
Finished loading module "/tmp/UnwOZdterz".
Finished reading indexstyle.
Finalizing indexstyle... (done)

Reading raw-index "/tmp/45N_dB_6Y8"...
ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string
```

Comment: Anyway, the culprit for this error is that there's an empty index key somewhere (or it consists only of command sequences like `\index{\alpha}`).

Comment: I am running into the exact same error. Here's your error, I quit, says `texindy`. How is the user supposed to troubleshoot that? There are no empty index entries in the document. What is next?